# Puppeteer throws "Protocol error (IO.read): Target closed." now and again

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

This is driving me insane... I have the following code:

```
// Load a PUG template
const template = await loadTemplateRoute(pdfProps.layout);

// Generate HTML 
const html = template(pdfProps);

// requirement for puppeteer to work locally, if using locally
const executablePath = process.env.EXECUTABLE_PATH || await chromium.executablePath;
console.log('executable path', executablePath);

// These are needed to run on WSL
chromium.args.push(['--disable-gpu', '--single-process']);

console.log('1');

const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  args: chromium.args,
  defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
  executablePath,
  headless: true,
  ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
});

console.log('2');

const page = await browser.newPage();

console.log('3');

// eslint-disable-next-line quote-props
await page.setContent(html, { 'waitUntil': 'networkidle2' });

console.log('4');

// here we can insert customizable features in the future using JSONB stored formats
const pdf = await page.pdf({
  format: 'A4',
  printBackground: true,
  margin: {
    top: '1cm',
    right: '1cm',
    bottom: '1cm',
    left: '1cm'
  }
});
await page.close();
  
console.log('5');
await browser.close();
console.log('6');
return pdf;
```

Running this gives me the PDF I want, but only like once in ten times. The other times I get either this after `console.log('4')`:

```
Protocol error (IO.read): Target closed.
    at .../node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/Connection.js:183:56
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at CDPSession.send (.../node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/Connection.js:182:12)
    at Function.readProtocolStream (.../node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/helper.js:254:37)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:94:5)
    at Page.pdf (.../node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/Page.js:1021:12)
```

Or other times (more seldom) this after `console.log('3')`:

```
Navigation failed because browser has disconnected!
    at CDPSession.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/LifecycleWatcher.js:46:107)
    at CDPSession.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at CDPSession.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:475:20)
    at CDPSession._onClosed (.../node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/Connection.js:215:10)
    at Connection._onClose (.../node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/Connection.js:138:15)
    at WebSocket.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/WebSocketTransport.js:48:22)
    at WebSocket.onClose (.../node_modules/puppeteer-core/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:124:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at WebSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:475:20)
    at WebSocket.emitClose (.../node_modules/puppeteer-core/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:191:10)
    at Socket.socketOnClose (.../node_modules/puppeteer-core/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:850:15)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:223:5)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:475:20)
    at TCP.<anonymous> (net.js:664:12)
```

I run this on a WSL Ubuntu but running it on Mac gives errors too (but less frequently).

It seems to be working better if I wait like 5 minutes between tries but listing processes (`ps -ef`) shows nothing running/hanging...

EDIT: Logging out what's happening in `/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/Connection.js:182:56` gives:

```
send(); Page.printToPDF {
  transferMode: 'ReturnAsStream',
  landscape: false,
  displayHeaderFooter: false,
  headerTemplate: '',
  footerTemplate: '',
  printBackground: true,
  scale: 1,
  paperWidth: 8.27,
  paperHeight: 11.7,
  marginTop: 0.39375,
  marginBottom: 0.39375,
  marginLeft: 0.39375,
  marginRight: 0.39375,
  pageRanges: '',
  preferCSSPageSize: false
}
send(); IO.read { handle: '1' }
send(); IO.read { handle: '1' }
```

The `Page.printToPDF` works fine, the first `IO.read` also is working while the second `IO.read` throws the error...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and resolved it by

1. replacing `page.pdf()` with `page.createPDFStream()` ([docs here](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.createpdfstream))
2. adding a 60 seconds timeout to `page.createPDFStream()` and `page.setContent` (defaults to 30 sec)
3. waiting for `['load', 'domcontentloaded']` events to be fired

**Example**

```js
await page.setContent(html, {
  timeout: 60000,
  waitUntil: ['load', 'domcontentloaded'],
});

await page.emulateMediaType('screen');

// const pdf = await page.pdf({
const pdfStream = await page.createPDFStream({
  timeout: 60000,
  format: 'A4',
  margin: { top: '0.5cm', right: '1cm', bottom: '0.8cm', left: '1cm' },
  printBackground: true,
});

// ...

// do something with the PDF stream, e.g. save to file
pdfStream
  .on('end', () => console.log('pdfStream done'))
  .on('error', (err) => console.log(err))
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('my-form.pdf'));
```

Answer (score 1):

After trying a bunch of things I started suspecting external sources as it worked fine with simple templates.

Reworking the templates to not load any external CSS and instead place all CSS in `<style>` tags and "pre-parse" all images to base64 (`<img src="data:image/png;MIIlkaa3498asm..." />`) it is no longer happening...

Clearly some load of resources that is messing with me...